# How to count with cases without subqueries in this situation

Tags: sql

I have a table grades[Student, Grade]
My task is to сount the amount of students, have 2 A's (2) and at least one D (2).
**The most painful part is that i shouldn't use sql subqueries**

That abomination i come up with would only list such nulls and students which fit by condition
Any ideas how to count them ? Or rework query?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
            (
              sum(CASE WHEN g1.grade = 5 
                     THEN 1
                     ELSE 0 
                     END) > 2
              
            )
            AND
            (
              sum(CASE WHEN g1.grade = 2 
                     THEN 1
                     ELSE 0 
                     END) > 0              
            )
            THEN g1.student_name
            ELSE NULL
            END as student_name
            
FROM grades g1
group by g1.student_name
```

Comment: Shouldn't use subqueries because...? Does that include CTEs and self-joins? And please tag the RDBMS you are using since solutions might vary slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any sub queries you can just count and filter using `having` and conditional `sum`

```
select Student
from Grades
group by Student
having sum(case when Grade='A' then 1 end)=2
and sum(case when Grade='D' then 1 end)>0
```

**Edit**

To get just the count of qualifying rows you can do

```
select distinct count(*) over()
from Grades
group by Student
having sum(case when Grade='A' then 1 end)=2
and sum(case when Grade='D' then 1 end)>0
```

Comment: @LunaeLumen Ok it looks like a slight misunderstanding of your question - this is where an example with sample data and expected results helps for clarity. If you want *just* the count of qualifying students you can do `distinct count(*) over()`

Comment: Tried over() too already, seems ok. Thanks so much!
Brainbugged a lot with that one.

Answer (score 1):

Oh how I miss homework....
Depending on your database, you can use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM grades PIVOT (COUNT(*) AS CNT FOR grade IN (5 AS A, 2 AS D)) g
WHERE g.a_cnt >= 2 AND g.d_cnt > 0;
```

Alternate:

```sql
SELECT g.student
FROM grades g
GROUP BY g.student
HAVING COUNT(DECODE(g.grade, 5, 1, NULL)) >= 2 AND COUNT(DECODE(g.grade, 2, 1, NULL)) > 0;
```